# NgRx Reducer - Change State of a specific object in an array

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to follow the NgRx walkthrough but adapt it to something a bit more complex than adding or removing books.

[NgRx Walkthrough](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/walkthrough)

I want to have an array of University Objects, and be able to find a university by Id then change it's total_student number.

I am nearly there. Completely stuck with the reducers.

**Models/univeristy.model.ts:**

```
export interface University {

    id: string | undefined;
    name: string | undefined;
    total_students: number | undefined;
}
```

**Actions/university.actions.ts:**

```
import { createActionGroup, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { University } from '@models/university';

export const UniversityActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'University',
  events: {
    'Change Student Total': props<{ universityId: string, total_students: number }>(),
  },
});

export const UniversityApiActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'University API',
  events: {
    'Retrieved Universities': props<{ universities: Array<University> }>(),
  },
});
```

**Actions/action-types.ts:**

```
import * as ActionTypes from './university.actions';

    export {ActionTypes};
```

I am losing my way here...

**Reducers/collection.reducer.ts :**

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { UniversityActions } from '@actions/actions/university.actions';

export const initialState: Array<string> = [];


export const collectionReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(UniversityActions.changeStudentTotal, (state, { universityId, total }) => {
    
    // How to modify the state to change the total of a specific univeristy in the list?
    // Find the univeristy by universityId then create a new record for it with the new total?
    ...state,
    universities: { ...state.universities, universities: {id: universityId, total: total} },

  })

);
```

**Reducers/university.reducer.ts :**

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ActionTypes } from '@state/actions/action-types';
import { University } from '@models/university.model';

export interface UniversityState {
  universities: University[];
  status: 'start' | 'loading' | 'error' | 'success';
  error: string;
}

// The starting global values
export const initialState: Array<University> = [];

export const universityReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(
    ActionTypes.UniversityApiActions.retrievedUniversities,
    (_state, { universities }) => universities
  )
);
```

**Selectors/university.selectors.ts:**

```
import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { University } from '@models/university.model';

export const selectUniversity = createFeatureSelector<Array<University>>('universities');

export const selectUniversityState =
  createFeatureSelector<Array<string>>('collection');

export const selectUniversities = createSelector(
  selectUniversity,
  selectUniversityState,
  (universities, collection) => {
    return collection.map((id) => universities.find((university) => university.id === id)!);
  }
);
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the id, you would need to search for the university and replace its data without mutating the store content. You could do it like the following:

```js
on({...}),
on(UniversityActions.changeStudentTotal, (state, {universityId, total}) => {
  const universityCopy = [...state.universities]; // create a copy of the original, 
  const index = universityCopy.findIndex(university => university.id === univertisyId);
  // you should add a validation if "index" is -1 if it doesn't find any
  const searchedUniversity = {...universityCopy[index]} as University;
  
  // Modify the copy as you need
  searchedUniversity.total_students = total;
  universityCopy[index] = {...searchUniversity} as University;
  state.universities = [...universityCopy]; // give back to "universities" a 'new' array
  return { ...state };
}),
on({...})
```

Since you are using `NgRx`, you could also make use of `NgRx Entity` for CRUD  operations `(Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete)`, instead of passing in the `university id` you should instead pass in a university `object`

```js
on(UniversityActions.changeStudentTotal, (state, {theModifiedUniversityObject}) => 
 ({...state, universities: adapter.updateOne(theModifiedUniversityObject, state.universities)}))
```

There are also available operations such as:

- `updateMany`
- `upsertOne` (either Add or Update)
- `upsertMany`
- `addOne`
- `deleteOne`
- and many more...

For more information about `NgRx Entity` you can read the official [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity)

Comment: Thanks Andres2142, I will look into NgRx Entity. It looks a lot cleaner.